# How can I ask Thunderbird to show remote content "only once"?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird 52.0 on a Windows 10 x64 machine, in case it's relevant. I got a newsletter that I usually don't bother reading (therefore marked as *junk*), but, for this time only, I'd like to see the remote content. I have tried, but couldn't find anything on Mozilla's docs. I also tried looking for a keyboard shortcut or a cheat sheet, but, while I did find great ones, none of them had the `show remote` or `show embedded` keywords.

I want to know if there's a way to make Thunderbird show what's embedded **only once**, i.e. I don't want to mark it as **not junk**.

I've never had this issue because newsletters usually have a `click here to see in browser` link, but this one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue. While I haven't found a native Thunderbird solution I have found an add-on that provides a work-around. The add-on is called "Allow HTML Temp".

The add-on will add a button to your tool bar (above) and a menu item to the status bar (below). Set the menu to 'simple HTML' (using right-click), this will show you the html skeleton without any css or images. Then press the "Show HTML" button in the toolbar will display the full HTML only once. If you select a different email and come back you'll see only the skeleton again.

If you use this add-on it's best to check the "Allow Remote Content" checkbox in preferences because it makes everything faster. And you can always uncheck if if you change your setup.

The reason this workaround isn't as good as a native allow-once option is because it's nice that thunderbird loads the CSS but not the images. It's much easier to look at. But depending on your use case, this add-on could be a good solution.